# getting "out of bound" on prometheus_remote_write after 1h

Tags: prometheus, fluent-bit

We have a fluent-bit (FROM bitnami/fluent-bit:2.1.1) with input for fluentbit_metrics

```
[INPUT]
    Name            fluentbit_metrics
    Alias           input_fluentbit_metrics
    tag             metrics_fluentbit
    scrape_interval 60
```

These metrics are then remote written on a Prometheus using the following output:

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name       prometheus_remote_write
    Alias      output_prometheus_remote_write
    Match      metrics*
    Host       {PROMETHEUS_HOSTNAME}
    Port       443
    Uri        /api/v1/write
    Log_response_payload True
    Tls        On
    Tls.verify On
    add_label  job ${SYSTEM}-${COMPONENT}
```

Everything is working perfectly (we are getting the metrics on Prometheus), but after exactly 1h, we stop getting metrics on Prometheus and we can see the following logs on Fluent-bit:

```
[2023/04/27 11:48:28] [error] [engine] chunk '1-1682596100.504052004.flb' cannot be retried: task_id=0, input=input_fluentbit_metrics > output=output_prometheus_remote_write

out of bounds

[2023/04/27 11:48:28] [error] [output:prometheus_remote_write:output_prometheus_remote_write] prometheus-hostname:443, HTTP status=400
```

Any clue on why this is happening? Notice that the timestamp (11:48:20.504) on the log has more than 8 seconds than the timestamp of the log itself